# Mat-select doesn't show the icons on select one of the options

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I am implementing a select input with icons options, but when selecting one of the options, then the icons are shown as text.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select MatInput [(ngModel)]="element.gender" [value]="element.gender">   
    <mat-option value="Male">
        <mat-icon>home</mat-icon> Home
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option value="Female">
        <mat-icon>face</mat-icon> Face
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I also tries to set the options values as `[value]="'Male'"`, But it didn't work.

Here is a [Stakblitz](http://angular-st6uxb.stackblitz.io)
Editable [Stakblitz](http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-st6uxb)

Comment: would you consider using emojis instead?

Comment: I think that the emojis don't suit the formal website I work on. Anyway, if I couldn't find a solution for that, I will try the emojis. Thanx @SiddharthAjmera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any specific method provided by the Angular Team for doing that. You can check out [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746997/angular-material-maticon-in-matselect) for something similar here.

That being said, there's a light-weight and a pretty straightforward workaround if you consider using Emojis. You can get Emojis of almost every mat-icon on [Emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/).

```
<p>
  It must shows the icon near by the selected option, budoesn't!n't !
</p>
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select MatInput [(ngModel)]="element.gender" [value]="element.gender"> 
        <mat-option [value]="'Male'">
             Home
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option value="Female">
             Face
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

[You might want to check for its support though](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/emoji-compatibility-with-browsers/).