# How to create a dropdown from an icon using Angular Material?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I would like to click the alarm icon and that creates a dropdown menu.

I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746997/angular-material-maticon-in-matselect)

Here is what I have already tried on this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7twlq?file=app/select-overview-example.html)

I still have the dropdown input box, which I want removed, so I can only see the icon before clicking. I would like it so that it is only the icon and when that gets pressed, it generates the dropdown.

How can I achieve this?

PS: it would be great to see a demo of it on Stackblitz :)

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: @JulienLachal It's on the demo link above. But here it is again https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7twlq?file=app/select-overview-example.html

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear, I thought you were showing 2 different links of what you had seen, my bad.

Comment: `boolean` flag will do a trick but not sure this is what you wanted? To achieve this in a proper way need to apply CSS

Comment: You need to try to hide the arrow, put no background on the `mat-form-field-underline` and reposition the `mat-icon` of the alarm clock

Comment: Cool, mind forking the stackblitz example and demonstrating this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you're looking for just by using some CSS, essentially hiding the `.mat-select-arrow-wrapper` element and adjusting some padding.

I've created a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7twlq-qboini) that you can have a look at.

Comment: thanks for the answer, can the underline be removed as well so it is just the icon that is visible?

Comment: @apollowebdesigns yes, I already had that in mind and if you look in the style.css file, you can uncomment that chunk to get rid of the underline too.

Answer (score 0):

Nowdays i think someone would use the Angular Material Menu Component.
see [Angular Material Docs: Menu Component Example "Menu with icons"](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples#menu-icons).

*If someone stumbles over this like my colleague.*