# Angular: MatSelect with visible MatIcon after select

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Make component **Labels**

make dropdown with icons - all works perfectly

but after select one of values i saw text, not an icon

my code:

***.ts**

```
export class MarkComponent {
  @Input() control: MarkDTO = null;
  @Input() marks: MarkDTO[] = [];
  @Output() change: EventEmitter<MarkDTO> = new EventEmitter<MarkDTO>();
}
```

***.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Метка" formControlName="control">
    <mat-select-trigger *ngIf="control">
      <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>&nbsp;{{control.name}}
    </mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option [value]="null">
  <mat-icon [ngStyle]="{'color': 'white'}">home</mat-icon>&nbsp;Не выбрана
</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let mark of marks" [value]="mark">
      <mat-icon [ngStyle]="{'color': mark.color}">home</mat-icon>&nbsp;{{mark.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

i saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746997/angular-material-maticon-in-matselect) solution, but it didn't help

**result:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

*no errors in console*

**UPD:**

**[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t52yj2)**