# mat-option with a delete functionality

Tags: angular, angular-material

So i have a requirement to display a list of options in a dropdown as well as display an "x" besides each option on clicking of which the option should be deleted from the list. I have achieved this functionality

`<mat-select "some css class">
<mat-option *ngFor="let singleitem of mylist">
<span "some css classes for right align" (click)="deletetheitemmethod($event,opt)">x</span>
</mat-option>
</mat-select>`

This works fine, however when the user selects an option, the mat-select displays a selectedvalue as

"singleitem**x**"

that x at the end is undesirable.
The selectedvalue should only be displayed as

"singleitem"

Has anyone come across such a scenario. Can you please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding "mat-select-trigger" will fix it:

```
<mat-select-trigger>
  {{selected}}
</mat-select-trigger>
```

---

To improve the given solution:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
    <mat-select-trigger>
      {{selected}}
    </mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let singleitem of options" 
      [value]="singleitem">
      {{singleitem}}
      <span (click)="deletetheitemmethod($event,opt)">x</span>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Wiki:
https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

Rel: [Angular Material - matIcon in MatSelect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746997/angular-material-maticon-in-matselect)